# How to Fix 'JavaFX Dialogbox taking user input' problem

Tags: javafx, dialog, iteration

[image]I am creating a JavaFx dialog box and I have written to a large extent the code. My problem is how to display the error message if a user enters the invalid input. I know I have to use a while loop somewhere but not sure where because of the structure of JavaFx dialog box. Second problem is if the user enters the right input, say 1 for yes, I would want to call a function to carry out a task.

The code I have written brings up the pop up box and prints the consequence of the user input to the console.

```
    public static void AnotherMatch() { 
//creates a popUp window
Stage popUp = new Stage();

// makes sure no changes are made in the Main window while this window is open
popUp.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
popUp.setTitle("New Game");
popUp.setMinWidth(400);
popUp.setHeight(200);

TextPanel textPanel2 = new TextPanel();
TextField nameInput = new TextField();
Button button = new Button("Enter");


//label explains how the game works
Label displayLabel = new Label();

displayLabel.setText("Do you want to play another match: Yes: 1 -- No: 2");

button.setOnAction(e -> isChoice(nameInput, nameInput.getText()));

//vbox stores label and is set in centre
VBox windowDisplay = new VBox();
windowDisplay.setStyle("-fx-background-color:Wheat"); //background colour is set
windowDisplay.getChildren().addAll(displayLabel,nameInput, button);

windowDisplay.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

Scene scene = new Scene(windowDisplay);
popUp.setScene(scene);
popUp.showAndWait();    }
```

Code for isChoice function

```
 private static boolean isChoice(TextField nameInput, String message) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     try {
         int choice = Integer.parseInt(nameInput.getText());
         if(choice == 1) {
             System.out.println("I want to play game again");
             return true;
         }
         else if (choice == 2){
             System.out.println("I want to stop playing");
             return false;
         }
         else {
             System.out.println("Invalid entry");
             return false;
         }
     }
     catch(NumberFormatException e){
         System.out.println(message + " Invalid .Enter 1 for yes and 2 for no");
         return false;
     }
}
```

The user should be asked to enter yes or no. If the user invalid input, an error message should be displayed to the user and the answer asked again until they answer yes or no.

Comment: Sedrick gave a great answer to this that shows how to use both bindings and action listeners. Now Im just curious, maybe Its just a better fit for the style of the game or just that you prefer it, but for such a case when its a yes or No dialog, would it not be more simple to just have a yes and no Button? Meaning that you would not have to check the input at all. Instead you could just add two action listeners, one to each button, and then perform your actions. Less clicks and also the benefit of not allowing the user to enter invalid values. Just some thoughts :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do is using `Bindings` to disable the `Button` unless the `TextField` contains `Yes` or `No`(ignore case).

Demo App using [`Bindings`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication357 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        TextField textField = new TextField();

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.notEqualIgnoreCase("yes", textField.textProperty()).and(Bindings.notEqualIgnoreCase("no", textField.textProperty())));
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane(new VBox(textField, btn));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Apologies for the late response. I used some of the lines of code and it works fine. The only exception is if an invalid input is entered and I want to output invalid message to the dialog box

Comment: I feel like this forces the user to enter the correct information before they can move forward. So to me, it eliminates the need for a dialog box.

Comment: I would get rid of the options to close at the top and set the modality.

Comment: @Robert also gave good advice. You could also go [here](https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/) and use something out of the box.

Comment: I changed this line in your code because 'bind' doesn't seem to come up as one of the options. I have to enter 'yes'. If I enter YES or another another combination of letter, it regards the input as invalid    'btn.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.notEqualIgnoreCase("yes", textField.textProperty()).and(Bindings.notEqualIgnoreCase("no", textField.textProperty())));'
'

Comment: My code is tested and works fine. I used JavaFX/Java 8. Maybe you are using a different version?

Comment: What kind of import you used for your Button?

Comment: This is the import I used for the imports   ---- import javafx.scene.control.Button; It works fine now. Thanks Sedrick